# Visual Studio/Basic how to write to a file online

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering how I could write to a file online within visual studio/basic. I want this because I have a register/login system, but i've only been able to write to the users computer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do would be to implement a web browser into your Visual Basic application. Then you can do things such as:

```
WebBrowser1.document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = "Donald"
```

Implementing this would require you to dig into the source code of the web page a little bit in order to decide what the proper names for elements are. This can be tricky for sites like Facebook who obviously try very hard to prevent people from making macros for their site. This is a valid option though and I've put this technique to use a few times.

Comment: How would you use this to write to any website? Wouldn't you need to have access to the files, then write to it? For example if i have a free hosting site, and a username and password file, how could i write to that specific path?

Comment: The code for any website is always in the "view source" page or "inspect element" right click option. Using the line of code I just provided you, assuming the site is using a generic ID for their username textbox would set the text in the box with the ID the same as if you typed it.